# Mouse sensitivity too high in most games

Tags: mouse, windows

It seems like in pretty much every game (examples are Skyrim, Deus Ex HR, Borderlands 2, CoD: Black Ops, PlanetSide 2, Far Cry 3), I have to reduce the mouse sensitivity slider to zero or almost zero, and rarely, even that's still too sensitive.

I use a logitech G700 mouse, on the medium ( 3 out of 5) hardware sensitivity setting. This setting works fine in windows (and games where I'm just moving a cursor around, like Civilization V). I could make a point to always lower the hardware sensitivity when I start a game, but I feel like that's a hack and there should be a better solution.
I don't have all that extra software for the mouse installed. I just let windows auto detect and install a driver for it.

In Windows, I use the fourth-lowest sensitivity, and have "Enhance Pointer Precision" unchecked.

My video card is an nVidia 560 Ti.

It wasn't like this before, but I'm not sure if it began when I got this mouse, when I moved from Win XP to Win 7, or when I got this video card (or maybe it's even been doing it for my last two video cards - the previous one being a Radeon HD 5770).

Is there something I can do so I can use reasonable settings in games?

Comment: I Have had my fair share of gaming mouses, and this issue seems to be resolved by simply removing the wireless dongle and replugging it back in. Also, what is you're average FPS during these games if I may ask?

Comment: The software helps, smooth out these issues a lot.  I'd suggest installing it and see if things get better.

Comment: Yeah, many modern mice misbehave if they don't have their native drivers and software suite installed to make them behave as intended. Even my Microsoft mouse works incorrectly if I just let Windows auto-install; it needs the whole software suite or it's a mess.

Answer (score 9):

If you install the [Logitech Gaming Software](http://www.logitech.com/en-ca/support/wireless-gaming-mouse-g700?section=downloads&osid=14&bit=64) drivers, you can have it automatically change the dpi and sensitivity based on which game you're launching. That may be the most elegant solution.